# Multi-Window GUI using Python Traits

Tags: python, user-interface, window, traits

How can I create two windows using Python traits? Something like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_gui = MainGUI()
    user_input = UserInput()

    main_gui.configure_traits()
    user_input.configure_traits()
```

The issue here is that user_input.configure_traits isn't called until main_gui is closed, but since I'd like to have interaction between the two windows this obviously won't do. Is there perhaps a way to mimic a 'close' function within MainGUI and UserInput without actually closing the window, so that the main body of the code can move on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is not traithonic.

What you should do is set up the user input window as a child window of the Main window, and use traits' system of event listening to track the user's interaction.  A very simple example:

```
class MainGUI(HasTraits):
  GUIWidgetsForMainGUI = Any
  user_window = Instance(UserInput)
  button = Button('Get User Input')

  traits_view=View(Item('GUIWidgetsForMainGUI'),
    Item('button'))

  def _button_fired(self):
    self.user_window.edit_traits()

  @on_trait_change('button')
  def or_alternately_you_can_use_listeners(self):
    self.user_window.edit_traits()

MainGUI().configure_traits()
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. If I wanted to have the windows pop up simultaneously on MainGUI.configure_traits() could I move self.user_window.edit_traits() into a custom __init__? And would this allow the user to go back and forth between the two?

Comment: Just confirmed that this works as well. It seems that with Traits there always has to be one model class that serves as the master class.. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can move interactions with the user window into `__init__`.

Just be careful, because in certain use cases with complex editors not all traits might be initialized by then, and your interactions might break.